# What's the difference, if any, between Soft Hair & Quantum Hair

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes

In the early 90s, John Preskill, Sidney Coleman, Frank Wilzcek and Lawrence Krauss presented a series of papers [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9201059.pdf)[[2]](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.1221)[[3]](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/1991/T36/028/meta) on Quantum Hair on Black Holes due to [Cosmic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string) in a number of ways involving for example the Aharonov-Bohm effect.

On the other hand in the famous posthumous Hawking, and Storminger paper [[4]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00921.pdf), the notion of soft hair is presented which seems to be a more intrinsic kind of quantum hair due to quantum fluctuations in the Black Hole's event horizon. The reasoning for this soft hair stemming from a [conservation argument](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/dark-star-diaries/stephen-hawking-s-new-black-hole-paper-translated-an-interview-with-co-author-andrew-strominger/).

What's the difference, if there is any, between the quantum hair mentioned in the two selections of literature?